# How am I able to loop my random number generator in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

vb.net noob here, I've been trying to make it so everytime i click "button2" it will generate a new number on a label, and that works perfectly but I cannot seem to make it generate a new number everytime the button is pressed I usually have to restart the program for a different number.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles generateButton.Click

    While resultString.Length < 40
        If overGen.Next(0, 2) = 0 Then
            resultString &= letterGen(overGen.Next(0, letterGen.Length))
        Else
            resultString &= symnumGen(overGen.Next(0, symnumGen.Length))
        End If
    End While

        Label1.Text = resultString
End Sub
```

Comment: Randomness doesn't mean uniqueness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that `resultString` apparently has class-scope it keeps its value and on the next click the length is still 40. So nothing new is generated.

Solution:

- Make that resultString local to your click handler (best option if you don't need that value elsewhere).
- Or set it to an empty string at the start of that handler, so you really create a new value.